# Using user input in a function and dictionaries with user input

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

```
def make_movie(movie_name = input("What is your favorite movie? "),studio = input("What studio is it under? "), running_time = + input("Do you know the running time? If not just type in 'no'")):
    if running_time == 'no':
        movie = {'movie name': movie_name, 'studio': studio, 'running time': running_time}
        print(movie)
    else:
        movie = {'movie name': movie_name, 'studio': studio}
        print(movie)
    return movie
make_movie()
```

My teacher gave us this problem:

> 4. Movie: Write a function called make_movie() that builds a dictionary describing a movie. The function should take in a movie name and the studio making the movie, and it should return a dictionary containing these two pieces of information. Use the function to make three dictionaries representing different movies. Print each return value to show that the dictionaries are storing the movie information correctly.
>
> a.    Add an optional parameter to make_movie() that allows you to store
>   the 
>       running time of the movie. If the calling line includes a value for the 
>       running time of the movie, add that value to the movie’s dictionary. Make at 
>       least one new function call that includes the running time of a movie.

I'm stuck on the optional parameter. If people don't know the runtime of the movie then I don't want the dictionary to show it at all. I made it so that the function asks for user input for each variable but when it asks for the runtime even if I put in 'no' it will still show the runtime in the dictionary.

So my question would be, is there any changes to my code that I can do to make it work?

Comment: `def make_movie(movie_name = input("What is your favorite movie? ")`  don't do this.  `input` will be called exactly once, and then that value will bu used every time the function is called.  This is a common "gotcha" moment you can read more about [here](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/writing/gotchas/#mutable-default-arguments)

Comment: Also, even if it *wasn't* a "gotcha" it would be an awful idea. Most functions should be abstracted from user IO. For similar reasons -- the `print()` doesn't belong in the function, but belongs in the calling code. You should return the dictionary, and let the caller print it if they want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oof, the biggest problem is falling for one of the more common "gotchas" in Python. Code written as part of a function header (which includes the default values for optional arguments) is only called once, and is run exactly when the function is *defined*, not when it's run. This is usually an issue when you create a mutable object there and mutate it inside the function, but will create problems here too. Imagine:

```
def echo(a=input("Enter a thing: ")):
    return a

def main():
    print("We're going to ask you to enter a thing now,")
    resp = echo()
    print(a)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

You'd expect to see from console:

```
We're going to ask you to enter a thing now,
Enter a thing: foobar
foobar
```

But what you'll actually get is:

```
Enter a thing: foobar
We're going to ask you to enter a thing now,
foobar
```

That's because the `input("Enter a thing: ")` line is called when you ***define*** `echo`, not when you actually call it. The standard change to properly implement this is:

```
def echo(a=None):
    if a is None:
        a = input("Enter a thing: ")
    return a
```

---

Beyond that I would strongly recommend you *do not*, as you mention as a goal, try to remove the running time of the movie from the result dictionary. Results of functions like this should be standard, and if I'm writing code that expects one of these movie dictionaries I should never have to worry that writing `incoming_dict['running time']` might throw a KeyError.

While we're at it -- why have the function prompt for user input at all? Do that in the calling function.

```
def make_movie(name, studio, runningtime=0):
    return {'name': name, 'studio': studio, 'runningtime':runningtime}

def main():
    name = input("Movie name: ")
    studio = input("Studio: ")
    rtime = input("Running time: ")
    if not rtime:
        rtime = 0
    movie = make_movie(name, studio, rtime)
```

Answer (score 1):

When you use equals signs in the *definition* of a function, like

```
def function(arg1=something, arg2=something_else):
    ...
```

that does *not* call the function with those values. What you're doing there is setting default values for when the function is called without the corresponding arguments. Python runs whatever code you write in place of `something` and `something_else` and stores the resulting values away as defaults.

So in your case, when you *define* the function `make_movie()`, as part of the definition process Python will run those `input()` calls to get some input from the user. It will store that input away and use it any time `make_movie()` is invoked without arguments. You can see how this works by appending a few more calls to `make_movie()` with no arguments at the end of your script - you'll see that Python only asks you for each input *once*, because you put the `input()` calls as part of the function definition.

What you should have done was to ask the user for input each time you want to call `make_movie()`, and pass that input to the `make_movie()` function. You would do that by writing, for example,

```
movie_name = input("What is your favorite movie? ")
...
make_movie(movie_name, ...)
```

You need to fill in the `...` with actual code, of course, but this is how you invoke a function with different arguments each time. You have to specify the values for the arguments when you *call* the function.

And of course, you shouldn't have your function have default values for things like `movie_name`. You want Python to notice and complain when someone (possibly you) tries to use your function without specifying the name of the movie, or other required parameters. The way to do that is by *not* including default values in the function definition. In my little example from above, I could write

```
def function(arg1, arg2=something_else):
    ...
```

and that way `arg1` is a required argument while `arg2` is still optional. Or I could write

```
def function(arg1, arg2):
    ...
```

and that way both `arg1` and `arg2` are required.

You should be able to figure out the corresponding change in your code without much trouble!

Answer (score 0):

You have a logic error here. Your if-else statement is backwards, that's all. Easy fix here is to just change:

```
if running_time == 'no'
```

to

```
if running_time != 'no'
```

or you could go and change the output around to correct this

Answer (score 0):

```
def make_movie(movie_name, studio, running_time=""):
    if running_time:
        movie = {'movie name': movie_name, 'studio': studio, 'running time': running_time}
        print(movie)
    else:
        movie = {'movie name': movie_name, 'studio': studio}
        print(movie)
    return movie
name = input("What is your favorite movie? ")
studio =  input("What studio is it under? ")
runtime = input("Do you know the running time? If not just press enter ")
make_movie(name, studio, runtime)
```

Here's a fixed version.  Note that here I'm still using a call that passes in a running time for a movie, even if the string is empty.

Comment: I'm not sure how useful this is because it doesn't explain anything. The OP may be able to copy and paste this to help with their assignment but they may not really learn from it.

Comment: The print statements really don't belong there. The problem description asks for the return values to be printed by the calling code, not for a function which prints them as a side effect.